# Database last read/access?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I was asked to get 'last read/access' of databases from Domino server.

The option - 'Maintain LastAccess Property' is disabled in almost all databases.

The business case is next. My customer would like to get overview what databases are used and when they were used last time.

What are other ways to get this info? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information can be read from log.nsf in the view `Usage\by database`.

You can also get some information from catalog.nsf: You need to create an own view to show all databases, as the default views are filtered, just remove `& !(DBListInCatalog = "0")` from selection formula.

If you need more detailled data, then you have to activate "Activity Logging" on the server. Just read about that in Administration help or follow [this link](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/activity-logging-and-activity-trends)

Comment: It took my 6 years to approve the answer, but thanks for different solutions. They are all really good.